# Correlation between threat and odour, taste

Tags: physiology, brain, human-evolution, philosophy-of-science

Is there any sort of correlation between threat and taste/smell?
Are we evolved such that things which are harmful to life taste and /or smell bad and things(food) which are useful to us taste, smell good?
How far this conjecture correct?

Comment: interesting question, if that's true the additives in food messed everything up

Comment: Seems true. Bitter chemicals are mostly "not normal food-component"

Comment: All-sorts of organisms apply their all sense-organs (what-ever a chemical receptor or not), to distinguish between beneficial vs dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

The compounds that smell bad to us are often the same ones produced by the anaerobic metabolism of bacteria, such as [hydrogen sulfides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_sulfide) or [butyric acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butyric_acid). These types of compounds are the ones that make excrement and rotting food smell bad, and if something is giving is giving off a lot of them it's a pretty good signal to not put it in your mouth. Vomit also has quite a lot of butyric acid in it, so we may be [particularly sensitive to it](https://thechronicleflask.wordpress.com/2014/11/29/butyric-acid-a-very-smelly-molecule/).

Plants produce toxic compounds to stop herbivory, many of them taste bitter. [Alkaloids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alkaloid) are often toxic and uniformly bitter, [terpenoids](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19817411) are another example.

There's nothing obviously different from a chemical perspective in chemicals that smell bad. Butyric acid is just a 4 carbon chain with a couple of oxygens on the end and reeks, while the compound propanediol (which is 4 carbons with an oxygen on each end) is used in [deodorants](http://www.tomsofmaine.com/ingredients/overlay/propanediol-(vegetable-derived)). If a compound has a strong smell or taste to us, it is because that compound has been important to us during our evolution. That doesn't mean it's a perfect indicator; cheeses can stink and be totally edible, but that's because the compounds in that cheese usually are a sign of something dangerous.